# Angular JS ui router not showing template (no js console errors)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Im just staring AngularJS app for 1st time. Followed some steps from tutorials but at the end ui router is not showing anything. Firebug is not showing any JS errors or warnings

my app.js file:

```
var app = angular.module("CRI", ["ui.router"]);

    app.config(function ($stateProvider) {

        $stateProvider
            .state("Login", {
                url: "/",
                controller: "LoginController",
                templateUrl: "views/login.html"
            })
    })
```

index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html ng-app="CRI">
    <head>
        <title>LOGIN</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"></meta>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,300italic,400italic,600,600italic,700,800,700italic,800italic|Open+Sans+Condensed:300,700,300italic&subset=latin,latin-ext,cyrillic-ext,cyrillic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/korisnik.css" />
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js" integrity="sha256-slogkvB1K3VOkzAI8QITxV3VzpOnkeNVsKvtkYLMjfk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/easypiechart.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.6/Chart.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
        <script src="controllers/loginController.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div ui-view></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

controller:

```
app.controller("LoginController", function($scope, $http){

})
```

template is saved in views/login.html

Comment: `<meta>` is a self-closing tag. Don't know if that's the problem but you never know. Also, check your console *Network* tab to make sure all the scripts are being loaded. Is there any content in `views/login.html`?

Comment: Ty for that answer, i changed my meta tag, also inspected network tab an all scripts are loaded. Template file contains login form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the root path, the state config `url` property should be an empty string, not `'/'`.

```
$stateProvider.state("Login", {
  url: "",
  controller: "LoginController",
  templateUrl: "views/login.html"
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Iypm5fXgpcrLS7Smlc62?p=preview

Comment: Thanks a lot your solution worked. You saved my day!